# Modifying class annotations using CDI

Tags: cdi, weld

Trying to use CDI extension event `ProcessAnnotatedType` to change `@javax.ws.rs.Path` of JAX-RS resources.

```
<X> void process(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X> pat) {
  if (!pat.getAnnotatedType().isAnnotationPresent(javax.ws.rs.Path.class)) {
    return;
  }
  final AnnotatedType<X> org = pat.getAnnotatedType();
  AnnotatedType<X> wrapped = new AnnotatedType<X>() {
    @Override
    public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(final Class<T> annotation) {
    if (javax.ws.rs.Path.class.equals(annotation)) {
      class PathLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<javax.ws.rs.Path> implements javax.ws.rs.Path {
        @Override
        public String value() {
          return "change_me/" + (javax.ws.rs.Path) org.getAnnotation(annotation);
        }
      }
      return (T) new PathLiteral();
    } else {
      return org.getAnnotation(annotation);
    }
  }
  pat.setAnnotatedType(wrapped);
}
```

... then after bootstrap, constructing the bean using `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager` was expecting the following code to print "change_me/...."

```
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(jaxrsClass);
for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
  CreationalContext cc = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
  Object jaxrs = bean.create(cc);
  Path p = jaxrs.getClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
  System.out.println(p.value());
}
```

... but this does not work. `javax.ws.rs.Path` is unchanged for JAX-RS resource 'jaxrsClass'.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`AnnotatedType` is an abstraction layer between CDI and the actual Java class annotations. CDI only considers the `AnnotatedType` metadata, but not the original annotations.

Modifying an `AnnotatedType` in an observer method does not change the original annotation on the underlying Java class.